# Creating Virtual Proxy Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, proxy, virtual-machines, linux-networking

I know this is not this kind of forum, but I can't find anything in google that really answers my question.

Is there possible to create a Proxy server running in a Virtual Machine using only 1 Physical Network Adapter (1gb Ethernet port) that manage the connections of more Physical Clients?

Thanks for taking your time in reading this and once again sorry for posting this here guys.

The virtual machine would be running over a Domain Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

If by "proxy server" you mean a web proxy, yes of course you can. Some commercial products aren't certified to be run as VM guests, but there's no technical reason that it can't be made to work, in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why that wouldn't work. You have a few open source solutions for a software reverse proxy/load balancer on windows. e.g. Nginx and apache. I like HAProxy in linux but that is not what you are asking for.

Don't expect the best performance though, you are using it on your windows server (i.e. not even a dedicated VM) and you are not taking advantage of the hardware acceleration that physical load balancers have.

Comment: The main system is Running Windows, but the VM can be running anything, I just wonder if it would work, I want the physical Clients to enter credencials in order to navigate and so be able to manage what, where, when can they access to the Intranet and the Internet.